# Handling Product Condition (Used, New, etc.) for E-Store Database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, product

When generating product tables in MySQL, is it more efficient to treat the same product with a different condition as a separate product, or to have a table for the base product keyed to a table that specifies the the price, inventory, and details that depend on the product condition?

```
TABLE product
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | INT()         | NO   | PRI | NONE    | auto_increment |
| model_no | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
| name     | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
| weight   | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
| mfr      | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

TABLE product_condition
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | INT()         | NO   | PRI | NONE    | auto_increment |
| condition_type | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

TABLE product_details
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id   | INT(11)       | NO   | PRI | NONE    |       |
| condition_id | varchar(20)   | NO   | PRI | NONE    |       |
| price        | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NONE    |       |
| stock        | INT(11)       | NO   |     | NONE    |       |
| ...
```

Or something like...

```
TABLE product
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | INT(11)       | NO   | PRI | NONE    | auto_increment |
| model_no       | varchar(20)   | NO   | UNI | NONE    |                |
| name           | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
| weight         | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
| mfr            | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
| condition_type | varchar(20)   | NO   | UNI | NONE    |                |
| price          | decimal(10,2) | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
| stock          | INT(11)       | NO   |     | NONE    |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
***with a unique composite key of model number and condition***
ALTER TABLE `store`.`product` 
ADD UNIQUE `unique` (`model_no`, `condition_type`) USING BTREE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to save product details in three tables ie.. product, product_condition and product_details. Because in this you can save lots of space, writing queries for different result will be really easy etc...

For example you can easily write query to find all product with `defective` condition.